# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 send dynamic variables to map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, parameter-passing

This is prob. very simple but I can't get it.  I have a href link e.g. `<a href="includes/driving.php?lat=38.254181&long=20.649962" class="driving" >Driving instructions</a>` which when clicked (using jQuery) opens a googlemap like this:

```
jQuery('a.driving').live('click',function(){
jQuery('#content').empty().load(jQuery(this).attr('href'), function(){
initGeolocation();
})
return false;
});
```

Function `initGeolocation();` grabs the HTML5 location and there are more than 1 `class="driving"` links on the page.  What I cannot get to happen is passing the lat and long variables to the map.  I need to get them into this function:

```
function calcRoute(position) {
var start = '38.313393,20.562651';
var end   = 'lat' , 'long'
var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
});
```

}

if needed the map is called like this (standard code)

```
function success(position) {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.313393, 20.562651),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
   directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        'map': map,
        'preserveViewport': true,
        'draggable': true
    });
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions_panel"));
    google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed',
      function() {
        if (currentDirections) {
          oldDirections.push(currentDirections);
          setUndoDisabled(false);
        }
        currentDirections = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
      });
    setUndoDisabled(true);
    calcRoute(position);
  }
```

Help appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi, well if you have your co-ordinates ready, then why don't you create `google.maps.LatLng` object  by this way: `new google.maps.LatLng(your lat, your lon)`, if you want to specify `string` then do it this way `new google.maps.LatLng("address")` and assign this latlng object to start and end. This will solve your problem. For more details please visit 
Google's documentation.:)

Comment: Prob is I can't find it in Google Documentation

Comment: plz visit here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests

Comment: Hi Nejil thanks for that, just I don't want to use a select box, suppose I could add the variables to hidden inputs and call by ID, but would prefer to use the get

Comment: sorry! its just not clear what you want. will you plz explain

Comment: Oops OK in simple terms - click link with the get variables lat/long - create map and pass lat & long to the function calcRoute(position) so they become the end points of the route

Answer (score 0):

You could get the PHP variables, pass lat and long to javascript vars and then use both vars in your calcRoute function:

```
var lat = "<?= $lat ?>";
var long = "<?= $long ?>";

function calcRoute(lat, long) {
   var start = '38.313393,20.562651';
   var end   = lat , long;
   var request = {
       origin:start,
       destination:end,
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
   };
   directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
});
```

And you could call:

```
calcRoute(lat, long);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I get it. You want to get the attributes lat and long from the link and pass them to the calcRoute function. Ok, do this [elem is the current `<A href...>` element, name is 'lat' or 'long':

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var lat=getParameterByName(elem, "lat");
var long=getParameterByName(elem, "long");
```

Function ripped from [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript).